# Group the values using one column and return the one having max value in other column using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, group-by

Following is a sample of my dataframe :

```
revisionId  | itemId    | wikidataType
290397666   | 23        | Q5
307190482   | 23        | Q5
292002833   | 80        | Q5
292428272   | 80        | Q5
305018745   | 80        | Q5
305018964   | 80        | Q5
305019084   | 80        | Q5
301731639   | 181       | Q5
303692414   | 181       | Q5
306600439   | 192       | Q5
294596767   | 206       | Q5
294597048   | 206       | Q5
```

I want to group the elements using itemId column and return only one row for each item which will have maximum revisionId. I have already sorted them based on wikidataType,itemId and revisionId. Following is how I want my dataframe to be look like:

```
revisionId  | itemId    | wikidataType
307190482   | 23        | Q5
305019084   | 80        | Q5
303692414   | 181       | Q5
306600439   | 192       | Q5
294597048   | 206       | Q5
```

Moreover, here this wikidataType column contains only one value 'Q5'. But in whole dataframe, there are 100 different types. But that might not be an issue because I can iterate over these 100 types since I have already fixed their values. Does anyone has idea about this?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with select columns for check `dupes` and keep only last value:

```
df = (df.sort_values(by=['wikidataType', 'itemId', 'revisionId']) 
        .drop_duplicates(['itemId','wikidataType'], keep='last'))
print (df)
    revisionId  itemId wikidataType
1    307190482      23           Q5
6    305019084      80           Q5
8    303692414     181           Q5
9    306600439     192           Q5
11   294597048     206           Q5
```

Comment: Will the first approach work if I will sort first like df.sort_values(by=['wikidataType', 'itemId', 'revisionId']) and then apply group_by as u said? Its a huge dataframe so cannot verify propertly.

Comment: Exactly, need sorting, I have to test it a bit.

Comment: I test it and need sorting by your comment, I edit answer by it.

Comment: Just a one more question, what if I have to restrict them to count 100 for each distinct wikidataType after doing all above processing?.

Comment: Need `df = df[df.groupby('wikidataType')['wikidataType'].cumcount() < 100]`